# Why is visual studio not responding when program running?

Tags: visual-studio, graphics, geometry, rendering

I'm building rendering engine to process geometry. Long story short, when it processes a simple model, say a cube, everything works. But when process a complex model, say the famous Stanford bunny, Visual Studio just simply not responding according to task manager, no crashes, no error, just not responding. What could be the issues? And what're the potential solutions? Thanks!!

Comment: Have you checked the CPU load?

Comment: @Jose before no responding, it's ~12%, after no responding, ~7%. (I checked CPU load on task manager)

Answer (score 1):

Oh it's working, just took a real long time, about 2 min -_-